# swiftでサーバーにリクエストを送ると「nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003」となる

Tags: swift, php

swiftからalamofireというライブラリを使ってGETでサーバーにリクエストしたのですが、
「nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003」
というエラーが出てしまいます。
前までは普通にリクエストできていたのに突然通信ができなくなり困っています。
サーバーはPHPで書いているのですが、
検索したところ、PHPのソースコードに
「header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')」
を追加したらいいと書いてあったので追加してみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。
また、swiftで書いたアプリからではなく普通にリクエストをするとちゃんとレスポンスがかえってくるので、swiftがおかしいのかな？と思います。

Comment: 「普通にリクエストをする」と言うのはどう言うことをされたのでしょうか?問題の現象が起こるiOS Simulator上のSafariのURL欄に同じURLを入力してみたとかですか?

Comment: 英語版SOでの類似質問とその回答 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44947910/2322778